# Hovering over an element causes it to animate rather just change its CSS properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In the code that I have on this URL:
http://jsfiddle.net/y5nqyucs/8/

```
div#column {
    top:0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    border: 1px solid greenyellow;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 296px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 4px black;
}
div.background {
    background: black;
    opacity: .75;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left:0px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
}
#carousel {
    border: 1px solid cyan;
    margin: 35px auto 0px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    padding:0px;
    background: #000;
}

#carousel .carouselunit {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid burlywood;
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: auto;
}

#carousel .carouselunit .flipcard {
    border: 1px dashed pink;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#carousel .carouselunit .flipcard img {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    transform: translateZ(1px);
}

#carousel .carouselunit .flipcard .backpane {
    display: inline;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateZ(0px) rotateY(180deg);
    color: #fff;
    background: rgb(0,0,0); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(53,57,58,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(53,57,58,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(53,57,58,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(53,57,58,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(53,57,58,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(53,57,58,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#35393a',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
.backpane p,
.backpane a {
    margin: 1em;
}

div.up {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    height: 35px;
    z-index: 2;
    background: #484848;
    text-align: center;
}
div.up:hover {
    background-color: #aaa;
}
div.down {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 35px;
    z-index: 2;
    background: #484848;
    text-align: center;
}
div.down:hover {
    background-color: #aaa;
}


<body>


    <div id="column">
        <div class="up">
            <img src="./resources/images/up.png" alt="up arrow"/>
        </div>
        <div id="carousel">
            <div class="carouselunit">
                <div class="flipcard">
                    <img src="./resources/images/one.png" height="200"/>
                    <div class="backpane">
                        <p> Some example text, some example text, some example text... </p>
                        <a href="#" class="done">Done...</a>
                        <a href="#" class="done">Link</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carouselunit">
                <div class="flipcard">
                    <img src="./resources/images/two.png" height="200"/>
                    <div class="backpane">
                        <p> Some example text, some example text, some example text... </p>
                        <a href="#" class="done">Done...</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carouselunit">
                <div class="flipcard">
                    <img src="./resources/images/three.png" height="200"/>
                    <div class="backpane">
                        <p> Some example text, some example text, some example text... </p>
                        <a href="#" class="done">Done...</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carouselunit">
                <div class="flipcard">
                    <img src="./resources/images/four.png" height="200"/>
                    <div class="backpane">
                        <p> Some example text, some example text, some example text... </p>
                        <a href="#" class="done">Done...</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carouselunit">
                <div class="flipcard">
                    <img src="./resources/images/five.png" height="200"/>
                    <div class="backpane">
                        <p> Some example text, some example text, some example text... </p>
                        <a href="#" class="done">Done...</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="down">
            <img src="./resources/images/down.png" alt="down arrow"/>
        </div>
        <div class="background"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- End Carousel -->

</body>

$(document).ready(function(){
var right = $(window).width()/2+629/2;

$("#column").css({
    right: right
});
var scrollDifference;
var justScrolled = false;
$(".up").click(function(){
    scrollDifference = $("#carousel").height() - $("#column").height();
    if((scrollDifference > 0) && ($("#carousel").position().top < 0)){
        $(".flipcard").css({
            position: "static",
            transform: "rotateY(0deg)",
            transitionDuration: "1s",
            height: "200px",
            zIndex: "1"
        });
        $(".flipcard > img").css({
            height:  "200px",
            width: "295px"
        });
        $("#carousel").animate({
            top: "+=200"
            }, 150, function(){
        });
    }
    $("div").removeClass(".hoverNowFixed");
    justScrolled = true;
});
$(".down").click(function(){
    scrollDifference = $("#carousel").height() - $("#column").height();
    if((scrollDifference > 0) && ($("#carousel").position().top === -scrollDifference) || ($("#carousel").position().top > -scrollDifference)){
        $(".flipcard").css({
            position: "static",
            transform: "rotateY(0deg)",
            transitionDuration: "1s",
            height: "200px",
            zIndex: "1"
        });
        $(".flipcard > img").css({
            height:  "200px",
            width: "295px"
        });
        $("#carousel").animate({
            top: "-=200"
            }, 150, function(){
                $("#carousel").stop();
            });
        $("div").removeClass(".hoverNowFixed");

        justScrolled = true;
    }
});

$("#carousel .carouselunit .flipcard").hover(
    function(){

        if($(this).hasClass(".selected")){
        }
        if(!$(this).hasClass(".selected")) {
            var verticalPosition = $(this).offset().top - 25;
            var horizontalPosition =  $(this).offset().left - 25;

            if(justScrolled){
                console.log('up/down button was hit and now flipcard is hovered on');
                $(this).addClass("hoverNowFixed");
                $(this).css({
                position: "fixed",
                zIndex: "2",
                top: verticalPosition,
                left: horizontalPosition,
                height: "230px",
                width: "340px"
                });
                $(this).children("img", ".backpane").css({
                    top: verticalPosition,
                    left: horizontalPosition,
                    height: "230px",
                    width: "340px"
                });
                console.log(verticalPosition);
                console.log(horizontalPosition);
            }
            if(!justScrolled) {
                console.log('flipcard is hovered on');
                $(this).addClass("hoverNowFixed");
                $(this).css({
                position: "fixed",
                zIndex: "2",
                top: verticalPosition,
                left: horizontalPosition,
                height: "230px",
                width: "340px"
                });
                $(this).children("img", ".backpane").css({
                    top: verticalPosition,
                    left: horizontalPosition,
                    height: "230px",
                    width: "340px"
                });
                console.log(verticalPosition);
                console.log(horizontalPosition);
            }
        }

    },
    function(){

        if($(this).hasClass(".selected")) {

        }
        if(!$(this).hasClass(".selected") && $(this).css("position") === "fixed") {
            var verticalPosition = $(this).offset().top + 25;
            var horizontalPosition =  $(this).offset().left + 25;
            console.log(verticalPosition);
            console.log(horizontalPosition);
            $(this).css({
                position: "fixed",
                zIndex: "1",
                top: verticalPosition,
                left: horizontalPosition,
                height: "200",
                width: "295"
            });
            $(this).children("img", ".backpane").css({     
                top: verticalPosition,
                left: horizontalPosition,
                height: "200",
                width: "295"
            });

            $(this).children(".backpane").css({
                position: "absolute"
            });


        }
        if(!$(this).hasClass(".selected") && $(this).css("position") === "static") {
            var verticalPosition = $(this).offset().top + 25;
            var horizontalPosition =  $(this).offset().left + 25;
            console.log(verticalPosition);
            console.log(horizontalPosition);
            $(this).css({
                position: "fixed",
                zIndex: "1",
                top: verticalPosition,
                left: horizontalPosition,
                height: "200",
                width: "295"
            });
            $(this).children("img", ".backpane").css({     
                top: verticalPosition,
                left: horizontalPosition,
                height: "200",
                width: "295"
            });

            $(this).children(".backpane").css({
                position: "absolute"
            });


        }
});

$("#carousel .carouselunit .flipcard").click(function(){
    if($(".selected").length === 0){
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        $(this).animate({
            top: "250px",
            left: "700px"
        }, 110, function(){
            $(this).animate({
                width: "700px",
                height: "450px"
            }, 250);
            $(this).css({
                position: "fixed",
                transform: "rotateY(180deg)",
                transitionDuration: "250"
            });
        });
        $(this).children(".backpane").animate({
            width: "700px",
            height: "450px"
        });
    }
    else {
        $(".flipcard.selected").css({
            position: "absolute",
            top: "0px",
            left: "0px"
        });
        $(".flipcard.selected img", ".flipcard.selected .backpane").css({
            width: "295px",
            height: "200px"
        });
        $(".selected").removeClass("selected");

        $(this).css({
           position: "fixed" 
        });
        $(this).animate({
            top: "250px",
            left: "700px"
        },250);
        $(this).css({
            transform: "rotateY(180deg)",
            transitionDuration: "1s"
        });
        setTimeout(function(){$(this).addClass("selected");},100);
    }
}); 
});
```

I have several boxes with an image inside them which are in between two gray boxes, one gray box is at the top, the other at the bottom.

Hovering over the image boxes makes it slightly larger and hovering off makes it go back to the original size. Once I click on the bottom gray box below it (which acts as a scroller to see more boxes below the viewport), and then hover over any of the image boxes again; it "animates" into a bigger box instead. If I keep hovering over a flipcard element it animates so that it keeps going in the bottom right direction. These are two undesirable effects happening.

I want it (flipcard) to not "animate" into a bigger box and smaller box, I just want the CSS change to make it go bigger and go back to its original size instantly and go back into its place within the respective parent (carouselunit) like it did before I clicked on the bottom gray box.

Comment: There are no images in your fiddle. You will need to host them somewhere and link to them absolutely.

Comment: I absolutely linked the images in my fiddle.

Comment: If the below answers don't work for you, try reducing the code in your jsFiddle and your post to ***just*** the minimal code it takes to work. Then we can more easily look through it to see what might be wrong. Posting the entire project keeps people from taking the time to figure it out for you. Do the legwork yourself and save us the trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're changing the property. What are you trying to accomplish here:

```
transform: "rotateY(0deg)",
transitionDuration: "1s",
```

Comment: When I click on the element ".down", it should transform or flip all flipcards back to the original side (showing the image you see in the beginning) and put them back into their ".carouselunits". What flips it to begin with - the click event handler registered on each flipcard. Taking out that transition-duration property solved the issue. Thank you.